# How to let Html Link (anchor) do a postback to be like LinkButton?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, postback, anchor, linkbutton

I would like to ask how can i make an html anchor (a element) or even any object to do a postback or to execute an server side method?
I want to create a custom button (a wrapped with some divs to do some custom them) and i want to implement OnClick to be look like the ASP.NET LinkButton?

Like

```
<a href="#" onclick="RunServerSideMethod()">Just a simple link button</a>
```

Comment: brrrr, i never want to go back to ASP.NET Webforms, hail MVC :)

Comment: sure MVC is new and good solution, but WebForms is still used at least for the old project (before MVC released)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, controls use __doPostBack to do the postback to the server.  __doPostBack takes the UniqueID of the control (or in HTML, the name property of the HTML element).  The second parameter is the name of the command to fire.

So for a custom button, render to the output stream:

```
<a id="someclientid" name="someuniqueid" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="__doPostBack('someuniqueid', '');">val</a>
```

In your custom button, add the `IPostBackEventHandler`, and this `__doPostBack` statement will fire its `RaisePostBackEvent` method automatically for you.

Comment: Thats good, but from where i can define the name of the method to run? or this should be in `IPostBackEventHandler` implementation?

Comment: You manually call the method you want to, or use reflection to dynamically call it.  You have the full control over the implementation to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 14):

Use a server side html control, [`HtmlAnchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.aspx) which is a server side a tag.

```
<asp:HtmlAnchor runat="server" onclick="RunServerSideMethod">Just a simple link</asp:HtmlAnchor>
```

Comment: This gets, "HtmlAnchor is not a known element"

Answer (score 5):

Just add on anchor tag --> runat="server"  onServerClick="Your function name", it solves your problem.

Comment: This is what i would use

Comment: This one solves my problem. It seems my version of asp.net doesn't have HtmlAnchor(or I don't know how to import it) & make a custom button is a bit overkill in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround could be :
 invoke dummyButton click in client side event of anchor tag - which will call server side event of this dummy Button by default. so if u place ur server side code in this dummyButton server event - calling anchor tag client side event would invoke this server side dummy button event.

Code:

```
<a id="ancLink" href="javascript:void(0);" >back</a>

<asp:Button ID="dummyRefresh" runat="server" OnClick="BtnRefreshOnclick" style="display:none"/>
```

Javascript:

```
ancLink.live("click", function () {
         callDummyButtonServerEvent();
    });

function callDummyButtonServerEvent() {

    $('input[id$=dummyRefresh]').click();   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this without relying on ASP.NET, RunServerSideMethod() should be a javascript function that uses Ajax to send a request to the server.

Try this Ajax tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ASP code from within the actual HTML code as following.

```
<a id="someclientid" name="someuniqueid" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="<% YourASPMethod(); %>">val</a>
```

This would execute a method called YourASPMethod() in the aspx.cs file.