# how do Creation postback on link in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

i use this code in asp.net:

```
string link = "<a href=\"" + Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "?Id=" + x + ">" + "link" + "</a>";
literalLink.Text = link;

<asp:Literal ID="literalLink" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

but i have postback in this link.

Comment: It's unclear what the question is. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: As is clear from the URL. Visitors click on the link to visit the page again. I want to do this with postback

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly (and I may not), you just want to display the link after a PostBack. If that's the case, you can do it like this:

ASPX Code:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="visitAgain" Text="Link" Visible="False" runat="server" />
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        visitAgain.Visible = true;
        visitAgain.NavigateUrl = Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "?Id" + x;
    }
}
```

Doing it like this instead of having all the logic in the .aspx file has the added bonus of improved readability and cleaner code.

Comment: ohhhhh!! noooooo :-) i want this code for my project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476982/how-to-let-html-link-anchor-do-a-postback-to-be-like-linkbutton

Answer (score 1):

If you want a PostBack event to the page you're working on using a link, use the `<asp:LinkButton>` element. It is the same as an ordinary button except that it displays as a common link.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Id="lnkButton" Text="I do a postback, yay" OnClick="TheFunctionThatHandlesTheClickIfNecessary" />
```