# unable to access a control in Master file from the code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, master-pages

basically I have a button in my navbar which is defined in master file. And I want to call a c# method when that button**(bt)** is clicked.
 But I can not access the control in code-behind. I also need to control visibility, so I believe it has to stay in one of those Views.

```
<asp:GridView   runat="server" ID="lw3">
                   <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="color:#ffffff !important">
                             <li><a runat="server" href=""></a></li>
                              <li><a runat="server" href="" title=""></a></li>
                               <li><a runat="server" id="btout">bt</a></li>

                            </ul>
                   </EmptyDataTemplate>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I see no buttons that are webforms controls. So while you can manipulate your `<a .../>` because they are `runat="server"`, you won't be able to easily run the server method when it is clicked - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476982/how-to-let-html-link-anchor-do-a-postback-to-be-like-linkbutton. You'd better just use full-blown asp control - it will be much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `<a>` link outside of Gridview to directly access in code behind.

If you still want to put inside the grid then you will be able to access these `<a>` link through grid by doing `lw3.FindControl`.

After you get access to those control then you will be able to control visibility as well by doing:
`btout.Visible = true;` or
`btout.Visible = false;`

I Hope this will help you.