# How to execute javascript code for raising postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, postback

I have following markup in one of my asp.net pages.

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl33$g_e246fa90_ed81_4990_9da8_88086176f196$Grid_Private_Pay','Sort$Created')">Created</a>
```

As you can see href contains javascript code, I want to execute this code in order to raise postback to server. 
I tried to trigger the click event of anchor tag but it seems to be not working.
Is there any solution?

Thanks.

Comment: See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2477078/4411339) comment on a similar post. I think it's what you're looking for.

```
<a id="someclientid" name="someuniqueid" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="__doPostBack('someuniqueid', '');">val</a>
```

Then add the IPostBackEventHandler, and the anchors' __doPostBack statement will fire its RaisePostBackEvent method automatically for you.